# Using server handlers with modal dialogs

Tags: google-apps-script

I am displaying a User Interface over a sheet using showModalDialog passing in the app I just created. I also setup a button with a server handler. When server handler function is called I try to get the app again using "UiApp.getActiveApplication()" to hide some elements and show some different elements, however, the changes are not reflected. At the end of the method I tried to close the app, and show a new modal dialog, I tried to return the app, I tried to do nothing, and nothing seems to work.

I can't post my whole code since it is very long, so I made a very simple version that gets the point across. When I put some logging statements in testHandler() it proves that the code is running.

```
function test() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(700).setWidth(1500);
  var label = app.createLabel("Hi").setId("label");
  var label2 = app.createLabel("GoodBye").setId("label2").setVisible(false);
  var button = app.createButton("Press Me").setId("button");
  app.add(label);
  app.add(label2);
  app.add(button);

  var testHandler = app.createServerHandler('testHandler');
  testHandler.addCallbackElement(label);
  testHandler.addCallbackElement(label2);
  button.addClickHandler(testHandler);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(app, 'Test');
}

function testHandler() {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('label').setVisible(false);
  app.getElementById('label2').setVisible(true);

  // Not sure what to do now
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return app; //where you are not sure what do do

Comment: Wow must have tried every combination but that one. Thanks for the help